# Mathutils not available

Tags: scripting

I let chatgpt write a script to to build an archway of bricks. With this outcome:

```
import bpy

# Set the parameters for the archway and bricks
num_bricks = 20 # number of bricks in the archway
brick_length = 1.0 # length of each brick
brick_width = 0.5 # width of each brick
arch_radius = 5.0 # radius of the archway
arch_height = 3.0 # height of the archway
brick_offset = 0.1 # distance between each brick

# Calculate the angle between each brick in the archway
angle = 360 / num_bricks

# Create a new mesh for the brick
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('BrickMesh')
verts = [(0, 0, 0), (0, brick_width, 0), (brick_length, brick_width, 0), (brick_length, 0, 0)]
faces = [(0, 1, 2, 3)]
mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
mesh.update()

# Create an empty object to serve as the origin for the bricks
origin = bpy.data.objects.new('Origin', None)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(origin)

# Loop through the number of bricks and create each one
for i in range(num_bricks):
    # Calculate the x and y position of the brick
    x_pos = arch_radius * bpy.mathutils.cos(angle * i)
    y_pos = arch_radius * bpy.mathutils.sin(angle * i)
    
    # Calculate the rotation of the brick
    rotation = angle * i
    
    # Create a new brick object from the mesh
    brick = bpy.data.objects.new('Brick', mesh)
    brick.location = (x_pos, y_pos, 0)
    brick.rotation_euler = (0, 0, bpy.mathutils.radians(rotation))
    
    # Parent the brick to the origin object
    brick.parent = origin
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    origin.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = origin
    bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='OBJECT', keep_transform=True)
    
    # Apply a random color to the brick
    brick.color = (bpy.context.scene.random(), bpy.context.scene.random(), bpy.context.scene.random())
    
    # Add a small offset between each brick
    brick.location.x += brick_offset
```

But I get this error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 28, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'bpy' has no attribute 'mathutils'
```

Apparently the Mathutils aren't installed so I reinstalled blender 3.5.1 and tried to manually install and import the Mathutils but I still get the same error.

I would greatly appreciate any help regarding the issue.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Please forgive my comment, but with all due respect, ask ChatGPT for a solution. I honestly don't see why the hardworking Python gurus here, working for free, should solve the problems ChatGPT causes... I'm sure someone can help you, but that's just my personal opinion (which doesn't reflect the idea of this Q&A platform).

Comment: This script is salvageable, but there are so many errors you might as well start from scratch. :) cos, sin, radians are functions of the `math` module, not `bpy.mathutils` *(?!)*. random is a function of `random` module, not `bpy.types.Scene` (?!!), the brick objects are not linked to the scene collection when instanced. Your bricks don't have any depth. I don't think GPT know of the concept of an archway, because it's instancing them in a 360° circle, when I think you want at most 180°. Also, bricks are not randomly rotated in an archway. Cheers

Comment: This doesn't feel right. Who is this for? I mean we usually help someone learn something by answering questions. This is not a question that needs an answer, this is a job task of fixing some script so someone gets a working script, not the knowledge of how to write it...

Comment: I am genuinely sorry for posting my question here. I pressured chatgpt for literal hours to correct its errors but in the end it actually suggested i might want to ask the question on this forum. I am aware that now that this is not the right place to ask this, so i apologize. Thank you anyways to does trying to help!

Answer (score 8):

We have to tell ChatGPT to [read the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html)! ;-)

It's `import mathutils`, not `bpy.mathutils`...

But worse, the methods you need, are not in `mathutils`, but in plain python `math`:

```
import math

math.cos()
math.sin()
math.radians(rotation)
```

So ChatGPT made a mess of it.

Comment: *"We have to tell ChatGPT to read the docs!"* ...+1 for that comment! ;-)